# Codeigniter - loading images from browser

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I've made an upload form using CI. 
Now my photos are uploaded in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_new\uploads*.jpg

I want these images to be accessible from the web, so i can add their path to my database, but when i try to load them via localhost/ci_new/uploads/*.jpg it gives me error - the image files arent there (so im wrong with the folder stuff i guess).

Could you please tell me where do i need to put the images, so the folder could be public for the visitors and so i can fill the path as an url in my database.

This is my upload code if needed:

```
function do_upload(){
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
    $config['max_size']='5000';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height']= '768';

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_erros());
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    } else {
        $data=array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
        //$this->db->insert('images', $data);
        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        print_r($data);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't there? It might be a permission issue. i.e. they are there, but don't have the right permission to view from browser.

Comment: If you have an .htaccess file, make sure it isn't affecting your uploads path. If you think it might be, just move or delete the .htaccess file temporarily and see if your images work then.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have converted your image file name in order to convert the special characters which is not allowed in URL.

Try:

```
$filename = explode('.', $filename);
$tmp_filename = str_replace(" ", "_", $filename[0]); 
                /* replaces space with '-' */
$tmp_filename = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '_', $tmp_filename); 
                /* removes special chars */
$tmp_filename = preg_replace('/_+/', '_', $tmp_filename); 
                /* replaces multiple '_' with single */ 
$filename = $tmp_filename.
            '.'
            .$filename[sizeof($filename)-1];
           /*Concatenating extension again.*/
```